# Unable to print time() with .format() in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Wanted to share a finding, I'm using `arrow()` module in Python and wanted to print the time, So I wrote:

```
import arrow

a = "08:26:18.788976"
n = arrow.utcnow().time()

print type(n)
# <type 'datetime.time'>


print "{first:20} {second:20}".format(first="This is the first", second=a)
print "{first:20} {second:20}".format(first="This is the first", second=n)
```

The output, is

```
This is the first    08:26:18.788976
This is the first    20
```

When using `n` variable, the `format()` function is unable to parse it correctly - and it prints the width instead ?!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make it a string

```
n = str(arrow.utcnow().time())
```

returns:

```
<class 'str'>
This is the first    08:26:18.788976     
This is the first    13:41:12.943499
```

Just so you know it was returning the number of characters instead of the time because you had not defined it as a string..

```
u = "type 'datetime.time'"
print len(u)
```

output:

```
 20
```

Comment: can you select the tick if it is a correct answer for you please :)

Comment: so, why `datetime.time` doesn't know it should use its `__str__` notation inside a print ? is this is a bug/missing code in `datetime.time` module ?

Comment: I thought the same thing.   The documentation does not say anything different.  Maybe you should report it as a bug